# Regular expression for wild card search in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, filter, wildcard

I have a string as **SEARCH0000123456** and  **SEARCH000096834**  and a I want to perform below search using wildcard *

1. SEARC*2*6 - should match SEARCH0000123456
2. SEARC*9* - should match SEARCH000096834
3. *123* - should match SEARCH0000123456
4. *834 - should match SEARCH000096834

So, * is the wildcard which should match any character.

Is there any way we can achieve this using regular expression in javascript

Thanks

Comment: Please read any available tutorial on regular expressions. Somewhere on the first page you'll learn how to match arbitrary characters.

Answer (score 8):

Just replace `*` with `.*` to match zero or more characters in regex. Or `.+` to match one or more characters. And also add anchors, because `SEARC*2*6` glob pattern will match the strings only if it's starts with `SEARC`, so we need to use a starting anchor `^` here.

```
SEARC*2*6   - ^SEARC.*2.*6$
SEARC*9*    - ^SEARC.*9.*
*123*       - .*123.*
*834        - .*834$
SE.ARC*2*6  - ^SE\.ARC.*2.*6$
?E.ARC*2*6  - ^.E\.ARC.*2.*6$
```

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that. What do you suppose happens when the user types `SE.ARC*2*6`?

Comment: i think it would be `^SE\.ARC.*2.*6` . Yep, it's complicated.

Comment: I know. But your proposed solution does not cater for that. It will be trivially easy for a user to break your approach by inadvertently entering characters that have meaning in regex. Simply replacing `*` to `.*` in the user's input is not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Mozilla have a good introduction to JS regex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

You just need to use `.*` to match 0 or more characters.

You may want `.*?` to match non-greedily (as in e.g. `.*?345` stop at the first instance of '345', not the last).
`

Comment: Thanks @Avinash Raj. Your solution solved most of my cases :)

Comment: @Phantom, did either of these solve fully it for you? If so would you consider marking one as correct, or posting your own solution that accounts for any other cases they didn't solve?